# sufficient conditions for finite time of existence of integral curves of a vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ open, $\partial U\neq \varnothing$, $V\colon U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ smooth.

Let $c\colon [0,t_{max})\rightarrow U$ be an integral curve of $V$, where $t_{max}$ is the maximal time of existence (to the right). Assume $c(t)\xrightarrow{t\to t_{max}}c^*$ and $c^*\in\partial U$.

Are there any sufficent conditions for $t_{max}<\infty$?

(Can I conclude $t_{max}<\infty$ if I know that $V$ can not be extended continuously onto a neighborhood of $c^*$?)